# Java Return Change in Quarters/Dimes/NIckels/Pennies

Tags: java, math

I need help with my little project i'm trying to make. It is not returning the amount of coins you need properly, the output should be something like this:

Amount of purchase = 23.06
Cash tendered = 30.00
Amount of coins needed:
94 cents =
3 quarters
1 dime
1 nickel
4 pennies

```
    ConsoleIO keyboard = new ConsoleIO( );
    double cashPaid, purchaseAmount, temp;
    int change; 
    int quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
    System.out.println("------------START--------------");
    System.out.print("Please enter total amount: $");
    purchaseAmount = keyboard.readDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter amount paid: $");
    cashPaid = keyboard.readDouble();

    temp = (cashPaid - purchaseAmount);
    System.out.println("CHANGE: $" + temp + "\n");
    double coins = temp;

    quarters = (int)(temp/25);
    coins %= 25;
    dimes = (int)(coins/10);
    coins %= 10;
    nickels = (int)(coins/5);
    coins %= 5;
    pennies = (int)(coins/1);
    coins %= 1;

    System.out.println("Quarters = " + quarters + "\nDimes = " + dimes + "\nNickels = " + nickels + "\nPennies = " + pennies);

    System.out.println("-------------END---------------");
```

Comment: Dont know the us currency quarter/dime/ etc

Comment: What do you mean _not returning the amount of coins you need properly_? Can you give us an example input/output?

Answer (score 0):

Your `temp` is in dollars. It should be in cents.

For some more thinking, refer to this kata.
http://codekata.com/kata/kata01-supermarket-pricing/